# django vanilla view set field after form submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model and am using vanilla views to create the Create, Update, Detail and Delete views.

```
class Person( models.Model ):
    username = models.CharField( max_length=30, unique=True )
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length=30 )
    middle_initial = models.CharField( max_length=3, null=True, blank=True )
    last_name = models.CharField( max_length=30 )
    last_four_ssn = models.CharField( max_length="5" )
    ssn = models.CharField(  max_length="13", verbose_name='SSN', blank=False )
```

What I want to do is create a form without the 'last_four_ssn' and then when the form is submitted (and validated) then I want to set the last_four_ssn as the, well, last four numbers in the ssn.

```
class PersonCreate(PersonCRUDView, CreateView):
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'middle_initial', 'last_name',
          'ssn', 'email', 'years_of_service', 'birth_date',
          'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.cleaned_data['ssn_last_four'] = form.cleaned_data['ssn'][-4:] 
        return super(PersonCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

But it doesn't appear to be working.

How do I save the ssn_last_four?

Comment: I admit I must be missing something stupid.  Googled all over and don't see how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the post method, like this:

forms.py

```
from .models import Person

PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

model = Person

fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'middle_initial', 'last_name',
          'ssn', 'email', 'years_of_service', 'birth_date',
          'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']
```

view
    from django.http import HttpResponse

```
from .forms import PersonForm

class PersonCreate(PersonCRUDView, CreateView):

    form_class = PersonForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            submited_form = form.save(commit=False)
            submited_form.ssn_last_four = form.cleaned_data['ssn'][-4:]
            submited_form.save()
            # return an HTTPResponse here, example:
            return HttpResponse("Saved!")
```

If you want to use the form_valid method:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.ssn_last_four = form.cleaned_data['ssn'][-4:]
        self.object.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```